# How can I place custom data into a UI-Router state from a Factory or Service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my example below, I have a custom data object that has roles. This is being returned from a function in an array, but I want to call this function from a service or factory.

```
.state('WorkArea', {
   parent: 'site',
   url: '/WorkArea',
   data: {
       roles: (function () {
           return ['User', 'Dev'];
       })()
   }
})
```

How can I get data into a UI-Router state from a factory or service method in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use the resolve functionality of UI router.

```
.state('WorkArea', {
  parent: 'site',
  url: '/WorkArea',
  resolve: {
    roles: function(Roles) {
      return Roles.all();
    }
  },
  controller: 'WorkAreaCtrl'
});
```

Where `Roles` is something like this:

```
.service('Roles', function() {
  this.all = function() {
    return ['User', 'Dev'];
  };
});
```

and where `WorkAreaCtrl` is something similar to this:

```
.controller('WorkAreaCtrl', ['roles', function(roles) {
  $scope.roles = roles;
}]);
```

Comment: this way is correct , but if i am adding roles inside a resolve then i am getting error like :- `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`  while loading `states` it tries to find correct path `data.roles:[]` and also in some of the function we are checking condition for role like :-  `if ($rootScope.toState.data.roles && $rootScope.toState.data.roles.length > 0 && !principal.isInAnyRole($rootScope.toState.data.roles)) { })`